# When I run gulp in my project it gives me this error "can't find module process-nextick-args"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I install gulp with this command `npm install gulp -g` then I go to my project and install it again `npm install --save-dev gulp`, and go to my project and created `gulpfile.js`, I write this simple code only to see if gulp will run or I have an error. This code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Then I go my cmd and write `gulp` then I have

[image: this error]

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` dependencies  and dev deps. Also the `npm` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you installed the wrong gulp globally. `npm install --save-dev gulp` should be used on the project, but `npm install gulp-cli -g` should be the command you use for the global gulp according to the [gulp homepage](http://gulpjs.com/).

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/a0ec3ff91c84baa1bd8de5331a502e330f5e3cfe/docs/getting-started.md):

> ## Getting Started
>
> *If you've previously installed gulp globally, run `npm rm --global
>   gulp` before following these instructions.*
>
> ### Install the gulp command
>
> ```
>  npm install --global gulp-cli
> ```
>
> ### Install gulp in your devDependencies
>
> Run this command in your project directory:
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev gulp
> ```

Comment: Globally i use npm install gulp -g in my project i use this npm install --save-dev gulp

Comment: I know, but the gulp homepage says you should use `npm install gulp-cli -g` for the global gulp, then `npm install --save-dev gulp` for the project